# Websphere server startup problem

Tags: websphere-6.1

When I start my websphere server6.1 in debug mode, I am getting following error in RAD.

Server WebSphere Application Server v6.1 at localhost was unable to start within 1800 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting the start up timeout limit to 2000 seconds from 1800 sec in websphere server setup.

Todo this,

1) Double click the websphere server in RAD.
2) Click the "Timeouts" link
3) Change the start up limit to something higher than previous
     In my case, I changed from 1800 sec to 2000 sec

Comment: I am able to set max of 1800 sec in the startup timeoyt field. If I give more than 1800, it does not accept my change. For example if I give 1801, it gets as 180. If I give 2000, it gets as 200. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Try delete all breakpoints and then start the server. Then put all the breakpoints that you need again. I get this error working with eclipse and tomcat, and this solution works for me.